# SQL query to count data from two columns (combined) of the table

Tags: mysql, sql, excel, database

Is there any SQL query which counts the total number of data combined from two or three columns and displays the total?

[image: data]

For example in the given table, column A has 1 and Column B has 2 so the result of the query should be:

[image: result]

and what could be SQL query if column A and B are common(repeating) but C has distinct data? Result should be:

[image: result2]

Answer (score 1):

Grouping on A,B and counting the results:

```
SELECT A,B, COUNT(*) as Total
FROM table
GROUP BY A,B
```

Comment: Updated the question, if you can help me with that. Thanks.

Comment: If C is distinct, which row should be selected?

Comment: So, it is same as solution you gave, the added criteria is if we take column C in account(which has different data value), how many distinct data are there in column C with combination of A, B repeating. Hope I explained it properly.

Comment: Append C to the `GROUP BY` list and to the `SELECT ` results.

Comment: I know my explanation is bad, If I add column C in GROUP BY and SELECT it will group 3 columns and gives you the output. What I wanted is group by A, B only but want to count the distinct value of C within the Group.

Comment: @Krin dont change the question considerably, once you have received answers for the original question. You should consider marking the best answer as accepted answer, and post a new question instead. Please see: [How to accept an answer for closure](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235). You get points for it as well. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

select A, B, count(*)
from TABLE
group by A, B

Comment: Updated the question, if you can help me with that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
      A
    , B
    , COUNT(*)
    , COUNT(DISTINCT C)
FROM
    table
GROUP BY
      A
    , B
```